# Add reference to c# project in managed c++ project

Tags: c#, .net, managed-c++

I am writing a project in managed c++, and I am a bit rusty with it.
I know that you can reference system assemblies with #using directive.

In c#, you can add a reference to a project. Is it possible to do the same in managed c++? If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 offers **References...** menu item.

Comment: Project + Properties, first item.  Click around a bit while you're at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project and then select References.

Under Common Properties->Framework and References, just click on Add new reference.